# django: avoid firefox back button restore the user session

Tags: django, session, firefox

Let me put you in context: Say that I'm logged in and I close my session. After loggout if I click on back button in firefox my private page is showed, my session is restored! That does not happen in chrome. If I try to do it in chrome I'm redirected to login page with next get param set to url I'm trying to go. So how can avoid this firefox behavior, or it's matter of django?

Comment: Clicking "back" does not restore your session, it just goes back to previous page. Browser behavior vary: it seems your chrome tries to reload the page when going back, while firefox just uses the copy it has in its cache. If you hit Reload in your firefox you should see that the session is invalid. This is why most sensitive sites tell you to close the tab/window after logging out.

Comment: What are you using on your front-end/back-end, are the sessions being invalidated when the users logs out, can you provide us with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

This is browser default behavior when you click back button, it load previous page from browser cache

you have to write a js function which will fire on when user click on back button, you can reload page using that function. 
Then you will see session expire and redirect to login page